# Dart // Flutter - How to connect image and audio to render a static video

Tags: flutter, dart, audio, video, render

I'm trying to connect an audio file to a static image and render it as video containing only the static image and the audio playback, I looked into several pub libraries like [this](https://pub.dev/packages/ffmpeg_kit_flutter)

but haven't found any documentation on how to implement when I'm looking for, is there a simple way to do this? and if not is it possible to accomplish using dart without writing platform specific stuff?

Comment: Update: I was able like many others before more to realize how to do this with the ffmpeg kit library, but it is extremely big and slow, is there another way to accomplish what i'm looking for?

Comment: Why not just display the static image with audio playing over it? Why does it have to be a video?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response :) @Abion47
The reason i need this to be a video is because i want to use the share package to enable the user to share the video to whatsapp/instagram/sms/etc..

Comment: Updating abit on the situation:
I found this package: https://pub.dev/packages/tapioca
which does enable some form of editting without ffmpeg, but it doesn't have a feature which helps to connect video with sound, only video with an image overlay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing, I hope it helped someone,
in my case I needed to connect an image to an audio file to create a video that can be shared with the share_plus plugin

You don't really have an alternative to ffmpeg, but you can set it up so it isn't so bad to use:

add this to your pubspec.yaml dependencies
ffmpeg_kit_flutter_min_gpl: ^4.5.0-LTS

import those in the files you want to render the video:

```
import 'package:ffmpeg_kit_flutter_min_gpl/return_code.dart';
import 'package:ffmpeg_kit_flutter_min_gpl/ffmpeg_kit.dart';
```

and then the render itself:

```
 await FFmpegKit.executeAsync(
                          '-y -i $screenshotPath -i $filePath -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a aac -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p ${applicationDocumentDirectory.path}/new.mp4',
                          (session) async {
                        final state = await session.getState();

                        final returnCode = await session.getReturnCode();

                        String output = await session.getOutput();
                        print(output);

                        if (ReturnCode.isSuccess(returnCode)) {
                          // SUCCESS
                          await Share.shareFiles(
                            ['${applicationDocumentDirectory.path}/new.mp4'],
                          );
                        } else if (ReturnCode.isCancel(returnCode)) {
                          // CANCEL

                        } else {
                          // ERROR

                        }
                      });
```